# Custom image for gitlab-ci.yml for frontend deployment

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci.yml

I want to make custom image for gitlab ci which has some default build tools and when I push on gitlab server it should fetch the custom image and install the dependencies.

I have made the custom image and its dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.16

RUN apk --no-cache add zip
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
ARG GLIBC_VERSION=2.35-r0

RUN apk --no-cache add \
        binutils \
        curl \
    && curl -sL https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub -o /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && apk add --no-cache glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
        glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && /usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 \
    && ln -sf /usr/glibc-compat/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 \
    && curl -sL https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip -o awscliv2.zip \
    && unzip awscliv2.zip \
    && aws/install \
    && rm -rf awscliv2.zip aws \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/aws_completer \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/awscli/data/ac.index \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/awscli/examples \
        glibc-*.apk \
    && find /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/awscli/botocore/data -name examples-1.json -delete \
    && apk --no-cache del binutils curl \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN aws --version
```

It uses node:16 image from docker and on it, I install the aws cli tool, thus, I can deploy the `/dist` on aws S3. Images compiled successfully and container seems to run also fine.

I have `.gitlab-ci.yml` in my project and  it fetches the custom image and then install npm deps.

```
image: customImage/Name

stages:
  - code_review

code_review:
  stage: code_review
  script:
    - npm install
```

I have tested on GitLab runner locally with the following command

```
gitlab-runner exec docker code_review
```

And, it throws error and warning.

[image: gitlab runner fails]

What I am doing wrong? Is it even possible to do what I am trying to do? Is it even the correct way?

EDIT: Retried again with same command i got this error now

[image]

Comment: The error says that the process was interrupted. Did you press the ctrl + C?

Comment: no. I didn't. But Now i have retired and it gives me the timeout err.